# Not able to send emails through my asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, timeout, gmail

I am getting Time-out Error.

> I am not able to send email using this code. I tried almost every
>   possible way but of no use.

```
try
        {
            string myString = "Hello I am new email message. I am delivered for testing.";
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("XXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXX");
            //mm.CC.Add("XXXXXXXXXX");
            mm.Subject = "Subject have been successfully placed.";
            mm.Body = myString.ToString();
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "XXXXXXXXXX";
            NetworkCred.Password = "XXXXXXXXXX";
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 465;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            Request.Cookies.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Response.Write(ee.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Where do you run this? From your own dev pc, corporate server or on a Hosting provider?

Comment: From Own PC and Hosting Provider.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private void SendMail()
{
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

mail.From = new MailAddress("Setfromaddress");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("recepient@gmail.com"));
mail.Subject = "Test";
mail.Body = "This is a test";

mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
try
{
    mailClient.Send(mail);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    WriteErrorOutput(ex.Message);
}
}
```

also I think we need to check the connection

To run the telnet and test on a Windows in your computer:

```
1.Open the Start menu, and select Run.
2.Enter command in the Open: field, and click OK.
3.Enter 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 465,' and hit Enter, or enter 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 587' instead.
```

Comment: What is the core answer here? The way you set the credentials?

Comment: I solved my issue in alternate way. But I like to Know what was the issue in  the above one.